# Adding a 2nd text column to a pivot table on the same row as first text column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, multiple-columns

My Data on the spreadsheet is set up in columns like this.
Project | Area | Disc | Employee | LOCN | NOTES | PROB | Jan | Feb | Mar | etc

My Pivot table has **Filters**: LOCN, DISC, PROB
**Columns**: Sum Values
**Rows**: EMPLOYEE, PROJECTS
**Sum Values**: Sum of Jan, Sum of Feb, Sum of Mar, etc

It works great by providing by Employee each project they are working on and how many hours per month with a sum of total hours per month per Employee.

But I've been asked to include the PROB (probability) of each Project next to the Project on the Pivot table for reference. I want it to just appear as a continuation of the project name, but if I add PROB to the Rows, it doubles the amount of rows by alternating Project on one row, then Probability below it on a separate row.

Is there a way to get the project and probability on the same row and then the Sums by month?

Thanks for any help!

Marie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `PivotTable options` -> `Display` tab and check `Classic PivotTable layout` checkbox.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!  This was exactly what I wanted to see.